# Haskell YAML QuasiQuotation?

Tags: haskell, yaml

I see there is `Data.Aeson.QQ`, and there is `Data.Yaml`, but there is no `Data.Yaml.QQ` on Hackage.

Did I miss a package or am I going to have to roll my own if I want to parse YAML at compile time in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a module doesn't exist to my knowledge, but you can still use Data.Yaml to perform parsing at compile time. I'm not sure of exactly you want to do, so I can't really give you more details.

Comment: I'd like to store some configuration as YAML to be compiled in, so that I can generate some appropriate data structures based on that configuration. How would I use Data.Yaml to do that?

Comment: Probably something like $(qRunIO (decodeFile "file.yaml") >>= lift).

Answer (score 0):

It's been added to `Data.Yaml.TH` in the `yaml` package (the quasiquoter name is `yamlQQ`).